# Is it possible to verify that an event is not emitted in Hardhat tests?

Tags: hardhat, events, testing

I know that it's possible to check for emitted events in a call in Hardhat using `.to.emit` method. Is there a way to make sure that an event should **not** be emitted in a call? For example I may want to verify that a transfer event with 0 value is not going to be emitted in a particular contract method.